# Convert column from string to date using jxl

Tags: java, excel, xls, jxl

I'm using jxl to read/write xls files. I need to convert an entire column which contains dates  as string (dd/mm/yyyy) from string type to date type. I just need to convert cells preserving their content and format (dd/mm/yyy).

Thanks a lot.